# Variance of estimator seemingly lower than CRLB?

Tags: variance, unbiased-estimator, estimators, fisher-information

While practicing for a mid-term, I came across a question where I was asked to investigate the variance of $\frac{(n+1)Y_{n}}{n}$ where $Y_{n}$ is the largest observation of a random sample of size $n$ from a $U(0, \theta)$ distribution, so pdf $f(x) = 1/\theta$ for $0 < x < \theta$. I calculated the CRLB and $Var[ \frac{(n+1)Y_{n}}{n}]$ and ended up with respectively $\frac{\theta^2}{n}$ and $\frac{\theta^2}{n(n+2)}$. The solutions manual seems to confirm that this is correct. Also, $E[\frac{(n+1)Y_{n}}{n}] = \theta$ , i.e. it's unbiased. How come we have  $\frac{\theta^2}{n(n+2)} < CRLB(\theta)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This estimator doesn't satisfy the conditions required for the CRLB to hold. Specifically, interchangeability of differentiation and expectation isn't possible in this case: $\dfrac d {d\theta}E_{\theta}\Big(\dfrac {n+1} n Y_{(n)}\Big) \ne \int \dfrac {\partial} {\partial \theta} \dfrac {n+1} n y f_{Y_{(n)}}(y \mid \theta) dy$, where $f_{Y_{(n)}}(y \mid \theta) \sim \text{Beta}(\theta,1)$.